# Conditionally borrowing in Rust, while keeping the value in scope

Tags: rust

I have a Rust function that can take a slice, but also has a default value. Then, if the user passes `None`, I want to generate a default value. However, because the data type I expect is a slice, I have to borrow that default value, but it immediately goes out of scope. How can I conditionally create an owned value and then borrow it, considering that adding a condition always introduces a new scope that will then drop that value once it ends?

```rust
fn with_default(foo: usize, bar: Option<&[usize]>) {
    let bar: &[usize] = match bar {
        Some(s) => s,
        None => { 
            let v: Vec<usize> = (0..foo).collect();
            &v
        }
    };
}
```

```rust
            &v
            ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
        }
        ^ `v` dropped here while still borrowed
    let bar: &[usize] = match bar {
        ^^^ borrow later stored here
```

Comment: How long do you need the vector to live for? Just for the duration of `with_default` or for longer? If it's the former, then you can make a `mut Option<Vec<usize>>` variable at the top of the function to hold the vector for as long as you need to, and only populate the variable inside your conditional if needed. I can write that up as an answer if the assumptions I've made are correct.

Comment: Yes, just for the duration of the function.

Comment: Great! See if my answer is what you're looking for then. I've used this pattern in nearly identical situations in my own code in the past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspired by [Silvio Mayolo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68765975/2148718), I realised that I can declare the `Vec` in the top scope, and only assign + borrow it conditionally:

```rust
fn with_default(foo: usize, bar: Option<&[usize]>) {    
    let temp_vec: Vec<usize>;
    let bar: &[usize] = match bar {    
        Some(s) => s,    
        None => {                     
            temp_vec = (0..foo).collect(); 
            &temp_vec
        }   
    };
}
```

Here's a playground link showing it working as intended: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3bd817cf2ffa10c131445c19be16cbfe

Comment: Oh yeah, this is very good. I always forget you can leave variables uninitialized in Rust.

Comment: Yeah likewise. I assumed you couldn't until I tried it.

Answer (score 4):

In Rust on your case I would always advice a little factorisation:

```rust
pub fn with_default(foo: usize, bar: Option<&[usize]>) {
    fn aux(foo: usize, bar: &[usize]) {
        println!("{:?} {:?}", foo, bar);
    }

    match bar {
        Some(bar) => aux(foo, bar),
        None => aux(foo, &(0..foo).collect::<Vec<_>>()),
    }
}

fn main() {
    with_default(5, Some(&[1, 2, 3]));
    with_default(5, None);
}
```

This have no problem:

- clear use structural pattern
- avoid Silvio solution that have an overhead
- avoid your solution that have an overhead

you can declare `aux()` everywhere but that a pattern I often use and so I put it inside the function itself, on "auxiliary" helper that do the logic.

Detail about the overhead you use:

Rustc is not smart enough (at least for now) to generate at compile time a perfect code so a "possibly init" variable will need a boolean runtime to know if rust need to call the drop implementation, on the case of Silvio solution that almost the same cause that need a branch to check state value of the option.

Plus: I hate the pattern of not initialize a variable I think Silvio solution way more clean on this matter.

Comment: This is an interesting solution that I hadn't thought of. So in general you have factorised the "rest" of the function into another function. The only downside I see is that it's a bit messier and you have to repeat the call signature. Can you elaborate on what advantages this has over my solution? ie what memory allocation am I making?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Migwell's solution doesn't allocate any dynamic memory unless needed. It just leaves a bit of stack space that *might* be filled with vector data in the future, but stack space is cheap. A quick check reveals that `size_of::<Vec<T>>()` is 24 bytes on the machine I tried it on, which is nothing.

Comment: I wonder if the overhead of another function call (and therefore another stack frame) in this answer will end up using more memory than this empty vector?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo yeah my bad I mixed thing

Comment: @Migwell MMM theoretically it's a tail call and so can be optimized away nicely. need to check godbolt

Comment: Mmh I didn't think about the conditional drop. I suppose that does incur some overhead I hadn't considered. Excellent point.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo of course this overhead is negligible we talk more about code practice and opinion here take the solution you want.

Comment: @Migwell look like rustc simply add instruction to allocate the vec and jump, no function call https://godbolt.org/z/4YPWq7dPz but I really not an assembler reader person

Answer (score 3):

If you need the vector to last only as long as the function `with_default` is running (i.e. it doesn't need to be returned from the function or otherwise outlive it), then you just need to make some stack space in the function for the vector. Since it won't always be populated, we'll use `Option<Vec<usize>>`.

```
fn with_default(foo: usize, bar: Option<&[usize]>) {

  // Somewhere to store the temporary vector. This variable
  // is owned by the function and will be freed when it goes
  // out of scope.
  let mut my_vec: Option<Vec<usize>> = None;

  let bar: &[usize] = match bar {
    Some(s) => s,
    None => {
      my_vec = Some((0..foo).collect());
      // We know my_vec is a Some now, so unwrap() is safe. But
      // unwrap() would move the value out of the Option, which
      // defeats the point. Option::as_ref() turns &Option<T> into
      // Option<&T>, allowing us to borrow the inside of the Option.
      my_vec.as_ref().unwrap()
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Even though I know that logically it will never fail, using an `unwrap()` in a function that shouldn't ever panic makes me nervous.

Comment: I agree, and I'd love to be presented with a way to do this that doesn't involve `unwrap()`, but I can't think of one right now. If you have an idea, I'd absolutely love to know it.

Comment: I think maybe I've found something? See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68766049/2148718. I wouldn't have thought of this without your answer though, so thank you.

Comment: While leaving the `Vec` uninitialized is probably the best solution, also note that you could simply use `let mut my_vec = vec![];` instead. Wrapping it in an `Option` doesn't have any advantage. Initialising an empty vector is essentially free, since all it does is zeroing a few stack variables.